# How can I put two search results statement as one using a conditional statement?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I need these two separate statements to be one statement using a conditional either `if` or `elseif` or even any other conditional statement which will execute any of the two queries and render results.

```
<?php
require ($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/medikconfig/db_medicpharm.php");

$connection = @mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_password) or die("error connecting");

mysql_select_db($db_name, $connection);

$doctor     = $_GET["txt_doctor"];
$len        = strlen($doctor);
$states     = $_GET["txt_state"];
$specialize = $_GET["txt_specialize"];

if ($len > 0) 
{
    $email    = $_GET["txt_email"];
    $hospital = $_GET["txt_hospital"];
    $state    = $_GET["txt_state"];
    $org      = $_GET["txt_org"];
    $link     = $_GET["txt_web"];

    $query = "INSERT INTO doctor_locator (autoID, `Name of Doctor`, `Email`, `Hospital of Practise`,`State`,`Specialization`, `Professional Organization`, `webpage`)
                    VALUES (NULL,'$doctor','$email','$hospital','$state','$specialize','$org', '$link')";

    mysql_query($query, $connection) or die (mysql_error());
}
?>
```

**first statement**

```
<?php

$specialize = $_GET["txt_specialize"]; 
$states     = $_GET["txt_state"]; 
$link       = $_GET["txt_web"];


$sql = "SELECT `autoID`, `Name of Doctor`, `Email`, `Hospital of Practise`, `State`, 
               `Specialization`, `Professional Organization`, `webpage` 
        FROM   `doctor_locator`
        WHERE   state = '$states' AND 
                specialization = '$specialize' ";

$retval = mysql_query( $sql);

if (!$retval) {
    die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval))
{
    echo "{$row['autoID']}.  ".
    "Name of Doctor: <a href = \"{$row['webpage']}\">{$row['Name of Doctor']} </a><br>"
    ."Email: {$row['Email']} <br>". 
    "Hospital of Practise: {$row['Hospital of Practise']}
    <br>". 
    "State:  {$row['State']} <br>" . 
    "Specialization: {$row['Specialization']} <br> ";
}

mysql_free_result($retval);

echo "Fetched data successfully\n.<br/>"; 
echo "<a href=home.php>go back to homepage</a>";

mysql_close($connection);

?>
```

**second statement**

```
<?

$specialize = $_GET["txt_specialize"]; 
$states     = $_GET["txt_state"]; 
$link       = $_GET["txt_web"];


$sqldoc = "SELECT `autoID`, `Name of Doctor`, `Email`, `Hospital of Practise`, `State`,
                  `Specialization`, `Professional Organization`, `webpage` 
            FROM  `doctor_locator`
            WHERE `name of doctor` LIKE 'Dr%' AND state = '$states'";


$retvaldoc = mysql_query( $sqldoc);

if (!$retvaldoc)
{
    die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retvaldoc))
{
    echo "{$row['autoID']}.  "."Name of Doctor: <a href = \"{$row['webpage']}\">{$row['Name of Doctor']} </a><br>"
    ."Email: {$row['Email']} <br>". "Hospital of Practise: {$row['Hospital of Practise']}
    <br>". "State:  {$row['State']} <br>" . "Specialization: {$row['Specialization']} <br> ";
}

mysql_free_result($retvaldoc);

echo "Fetched data successfully\n.<br/>"; 
echo "<a href=home.php>go back to homepage</a>";

mysql_close($connection);

?>
```

Comment: i don't get which condition should be checked :P

Comment: You have possible SQL injection vulnerabilities in this code.

Comment: i have two statement there, and i want them to be just one statement. but i dont know the conditional statement to use to make both queries work.

Comment: Do you need to JOIN the queries?

Comment: yes i need to join the queries.

Comment: @anabisystems - can you clarify this?  _i want it to run i way that if i query either of the two statement it will give me those separate results._  So, you always want two separate results in the same set of code?  Based on what values are provided or not provided, the logic should determine which query to run?

Answer (score 0):

the difference is

```
$doctor = $_GET["txt_doctor"];
```

you can firstly check  `$_GET["txt_doctor"];` and then with the code below

```
if(isset( $_GET["txt_doctor"]))
{
  // second statement
}else
{
// first statement

}
```

Comment: $doctor = $_GET["txt_doctor"]; is not part of the code, my mistake.please can you give me a solution without making reference to $doctor = $_GET["txt_doctor"]; thank you

Comment: How do you decide whixh query to run?

Comment: i want it to run i way that if i query either of the two statement it will give me those separate results.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very hard to understand.  **Formatting** your code helped me understand your question a little bit more, though...

**first query**

```
    SELECT `autoID`, `Name of Doctor`, `Email`, `Hospital of Practise`, `State`, 
           `Specialization`, `Professional Organization`, `webpage` 
    FROM   `doctor_locator`
    WHERE   state = '$states' AND 
            specialization = '$specialize'
```

**second query**

```
       SELECT `autoID`, `Name of Doctor`, `Email`, `Hospital of Practise`, `State`,
              `Specialization`, `Professional Organization`, `webpage` 
        FROM  `doctor_locator`
        WHERE `name of doctor` LIKE 'Dr%' AND state = '$states'
```

this query *only* filters for two things.  Where the name of the doctor starts with `Dr` and for the `$states`.  This seems wrong to me... but it is the code that you provided.  It seems like there should be a name you're filtering by.

**combined**

```
$sql = "SELECT `autoID`, `Name of Doctor`, `Email`,
               `Hospital of Practise`, `State`, 
               `Specialization`, `Professional Organization`, `webpage` 

        FROM   `doctor_locator`

        WHERE   state = '$states' AND 
                specialization = '$specialize' AND
               `name of doctor` LIKE 'Dr%'
```

The `$states` filter was in there twice.

**question** - it seems like you don't really want the two queries joined, you want them executed separately depending on something.  I need to know what determines which query is ran.

```
  If ($query = "run query 1")  { // run query 1... } 
                          else { // run query 2... }
```

you didn't provide enough information in your initial post for me to write that logic.

Comment: THANKS A LOT BUT I STILL NEED YOUR ASSISTANCE. THE ANSWER YOU GAVE TO ME ONLY WORKS FOR ONE PART BUT THE OTHER PART IS NOT RENDERING THE REQUIRED RESULTS. THE WHERE CLAUSE WORKS FOR                   WHERE   state = '$states' AND 
                specialization = '$specialize'

Comment: what part _doesn't_ it work for?  based on the code provided in your question, I don't know what else to add.  You need to clarify your question.  I don't understand your initial post or what you're asking for.  I can give you a better answer if you are more clear.